# iterating string in C, word by word

Tags: c, string

I just started learning C. What I am trying to right now is that I have two strings in which each word is separated by white spaces and I have to return the number of matching words in both strings. So, is there any function in C where I can take each word and compare it to everyother word in another string, if not any idea on how I can do that.

Comment: You can use `strtok` but beware that it actually modifies the string as it goes.

Comment: I've never had problems with 'strtok'. This is what it's made for. see this site: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/

Comment: Alternatively, use `isspace`, record the start and end, and copy it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Break up the first string in words, this you can do in any number of ways everything from looping through the character array inserting `\0` at each space to using `strtok`.

For each word found, go through the other string using `strstr` which checks if a string is in there. just check return value from `strstr`, if `!= NULL` it found it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd not use `strtok` but stick with pointer arithmetics length comparison and   `memcmp` to compare strings of equal length.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems here:

1) splitting each string into words

The [`strtok()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/strtok.html) function can split a string into words.

It is a meaningful exercise to imagine how you might write your own equivalent to `strtok`.

The [rosetta project](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Tokenize_a_string#C) shows both a `strtok` and a custom method approach to precisely this problem.

I would naturally write my own parser, as its the kind of code that appeals to me.  It could be a fun exercise for you.

2) finding those words in one string that are also in another

If you iterate over each word in one string for each word in another, it has [O(n*n)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) complexity.

If you index the words in one string it will take just O(n) which is substantially quicker (if your input is large enough to make this interesting).  It is worth imagining how you might build a [hashtable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) of the words in one string so that you can look for the words in the other.